# Apache Virtualhost on different port redirecting to DefaultRoot

Tags: apache

I'm trying to set to virtual hosts listening to different ports with apache 2.4

On port 80: A plain HTML page.
On port 81: An Angular6 app.

On my 0_web.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName web
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web
        DirectoryIndex index.html

    <Directory /var/www/html/web>
       AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

On front.conf

```
Listen 81
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName munitdp
    <Directory /var/www/dist/>
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html
        # to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using an amazon ec2 server. For now I don't have any domain so i access urls like http://ec2-18-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

Output of apachectl -S

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   web (/etc/httpd/conf.d/0_web.conf:1)
*:81                   munitdp (/etc/httpd/conf.d/front.conf:2)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex cache-socache: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
Mutex lua-ivm-shm: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48
```

When I enter http://ec2-18-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ I get to the html page, but accesing http://ec2-18-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:81 gets me to "Index of /", listing web/.

Any ideas? I've been hitting a wall here.

Comment: apache uses first vhost when no vhost matches to specific url. Your vhost for port 81 has servername munitdp, so url doesn't matches that and as a result first vhost is being used. Can you try removing servername directive from second vhost?

Comment: Done. Still same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see a DocumentRoot defined in the second vHost. Maybe add

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/dist/
```

to your front.conf

Comment: That was it. I feel pretty dumb for not noticing it. Thanks!